# Date greater_than & less_than

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
validates :start_date, comparison: { greater_than: :end_date }
```

is this validation is correct? shouldn't it be ->

```
validates :start_date, comparison: { less_than: :end_date }
```

I expect that start date should be less than end date, am i wrong to expect that?

I was reading rails docs [related_post](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entirely correct. i have made a little snippet for it:

```
class InvalidObj < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date

    validates :start_date, comparison: {greater_than: :end_date}
end

class ValidObj < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date

    validates :start_date, comparison: {less_than: :end_date}
end
```

Then in the console:

```
a = InvalidObj.new
a.start_date = 1.day.ago
a.end_date = Time.now
a.valid?  
=> false


b = ValidObj.new
b.start_date = 1.day.ago
b.end_date = Time.now
b.valid?
=> true
```

You can safely consider it as typo in documentation

Comment: You are welcome! :) then you probably can mark my reply as a correct answer ;-)